# Confusion about the reflection coefficient when a particle going through a potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, reflection, scattering

Suppose we have a potential$$ V(x) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $ x \le 0$} \\
V_0 & \text{if $ x \gt 0$ }
\end{cases}$$
The reflection coefficient for the case $E \lt V_0$ is $1$, which means all the waves are reflected back.

But I've got a question: we know from the calculation, there is some waves which can pass through the barrier, though decaying exponentially, then how is the reflection coefficient be $1$. Does that mean the waves which pass through the barrier will eventually reflect back?

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of the reflection and transmission coefficients, for the case $E<V$, $R=1$ means that there is NO CURRENT, or NO FLUX of particles at all. You can find particles behind the potential step: yes, it's true. But it does not mean that you can find a FLUX of particles. So, it is ok here.

Answer (score 0):

First off, a derivation of the transmission and reflection coefficients can be found [here](https://courses.physics.illinois.edu/phys485/fa2015/web/tunneling.pdf)

Second, unless I'm grossly mistaken, the reflection coefficient at a step potential is not 1.0, even for the case that $E < V_{0}$.

Comment: The reflection coefficient is exactly 1 if the potential has infinite width.  See the graph on p. 8 of your link.